# Wrong First name in domestic flight ticket

Tags: india, domestic-travel, indigo

Booked a flight ticket with wrong first name.Say her name is “venkata Sai matta” (matta is last name).while booking I wrote “Sai Matta”.Called helpline for name change they denied my request.Can something be done rather than re booking?

Comment: Is the airline office nearby?

Comment: It is indigo flight.I think headoffice is in Delhi which is not near to me.

Answer (score 5):

Well we (my friend and I) had a problem similar to this one, but we realised it right at the check ins, two hours before the take-off. After an hour of explaining and showing the ID and telling the man at the check ins that we were really tired when we booked the ticket and we made a mistake spelling the name, he finally let us through. I think it's just a matter of how understanding is the person. I don't think there is anything you can do, besides re booking. We were just lucky I guess.